# Regex to replace specified lower case char to upper case in Javascript Webstorm IDE

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm coding with [Jetbrain's Webstorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and have code like this:

```
'box-sizing': 'border-box',
'user-select': 'none',
```

I have to convert this to:

```
'boxSizing': 'border-box',
'userSelect': 'none',
```

I try to using Webstorm's regex replacement with regular expression:

```
(?<='\w+)-(\w)(?=\w+':)
```

and replacement is:

```
\U$1
```

But it fails because it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, regex is selected in search/replace fields of IntelliJ IDE.

In search field:

```
(.*?)(\-)(.*?\':)
```

and in Replace field:

```
$1\u$3
```

Hit replace. It should transform

```
'box-sizing': 'border-box',
'user-select': 'none',
```

Into

```
'boxSizing': 'border-box',
'userSelect': 'none',
```